# Android List View Edit All view apperance

Tags: android, listview, row, android-arrayadapter

I want to start by saying that I'm not using views here. I simply have 5 views and I swap them around with two selection clicks. I've looked through several questions online and most of them deal with the Recycler and getChildAt etc and it just doesn't work for me.

I understand how Adapters are meant to work so I figured I'd have to pass my background colour into my Adapter. Just a quick background into what I want to do here. The user can shuffle the list items around and they must correspond to the table next to it. Once the user thinks the answers are correct they hit the submit button. At this point the background colours should change to green or red for correct and incorrect.

However when I want to access all the views I can't seem to get a handle on it.

**Getting my data source for the adapter**

```
    private ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> testArray = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> getDefinitionWordsTriplet(){
    testArray.add(Triplet.with("Trojan", 0, Color.WHITE));
    testArray.add(Triplet.with("Virus", 1, Color.WHITE));
    testArray.add(Triplet.with("Spyware", 2, Color.WHITE));
    testArray.add(Triplet.with("Ransomware", 3, Color.WHITE));
    testArray.add(Triplet.with("Leakware", 4, Color.WHITE));
    return testArray;
}
```

So I'm using an API to use a Triplet, originally this was a Pair but I decided to include the colour Int.

**Populating the adapter**

```
 //TESTING
private ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> testTripletArray;
private DefintionListViewAdapterTriplet leftTripletAdapter;

private void EstablishTableLists(){
    leftDefinitionLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.definitionMainGameLeftLV);
    ListView rightDefinitionLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.definitionMainGameRightLV);

    DefinitionWordList wordAndDefinitionList = new DefinitionWordList();
    definitionWordsList = wordAndDefinitionList.getDefinitionWords();
    definitionExplanationsList = wordAndDefinitionList.getDefinitionExplanations();
    tableLength = definitionWordsList.size();

    //TESTING
    testTripletArray = wordAndDefinitionList.getDefinitionWordsTriplet();

    DefintionListViewAdapter rightAdapter = new DefintionListViewAdapter
            (DefinitionGameMainActivity.this, definitionExplanationsList);

    //TESTING
    leftTripletAdapter = new DefintionListViewAdapterTriplet(DefinitionGameMainActivity.this, testTripletArray);

    //leftDefinitionLV.setAdapter(leftAdapter);
    rightDefinitionLV.setAdapter(rightAdapter);

    //TESTING
    leftDefinitionLV.setAdapter(leftTripletAdapter);

    leftDefinitionLV.setOnItemClickListener(leftSideItemListener);

}
```

So this is standard adapter and listView establishment. I pass in my data to the adapter and then give the listView my adapter.

**The Adapter**

```
public class DefintionListViewAdapterTriplet extends ArrayAdapter<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> mInput;

public DefintionListViewAdapterTriplet(Context c, ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> input){
    super(c, -1, input);
    mContext = c;
    mInput = input;
    Log.i("Test: ", mInput.get(0).getValue0());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.definition_table_cell, parent, false);

    TextView textInputTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.definitionCellTV);
    LinearLayout borderColour = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.definitionBackgroundCell);
    borderColour.setBackgroundColor(mInput.get(position).getValue2());
    textInputTV.setText(mInput.get(position).getValue0());
/*        if(parent.getId() == R.id.definitionTutorialRightTableLV || parent.getId() == R.id.definitionMainGameRightLV){
        borderColour.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.definition_tutorial_box_border_grey);
    }else{

    }*/
    return rowView;
}
```

Again nothing specifically fancy with the adapter. I've commented out the border box background because I'm testing the colour assignment. So as I put the background colour here from the 3rd parameter of the Triplet I thought I'd be able to modify it in the main activity.

**Trying to modify each view and notify**

```
    private void checkAnswerValues(){
    for(int i = 0; i < tableLength; i++){
        //int leftCell = definitionWordsList.get(i).second;

        //TESTING
        int leftCell = testTripletArray.get(i).getValue1();
        int rightCell = definitionExplanationsList.get(i).second;
        //TODO Doesn't work, doesn;t update the colours. No crashing but unsure
        //TODO Don't think it's getting the right information, need to think how to access a view.
        if(leftCell == rightCell){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Match");
            correctAnswerCount++;
            //TODO CHange border colours in both tables to green
            testTripletArray.get(i).setAt2(Color.GREEN);
        }else{
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "No Match");
            //TODO Change border colours to red
            testTripletArray.get(i).setAt2(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    leftTripletAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the stage at which I want the user to press the check answer button and it cycles through all of the definitions and words to see if they match. It's based on an index set as the 2nd (1st if you count from 0) argument of the Triple.

I finally try to change the background colour int of the triplet with setAt2 and then select the colour. After the for loop I notify the adapter that the information has changed. I was then hoping that the adapter would update the "getView" and apply the new argument found in the colour parameter. Unfortunately nothing updates.

Any advice here would be great as I've been testing lots of difference methods but I've come up short.

Thanks for reading, I know it's a long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main reasons `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't work for you - is, your adapter loses the reference to your list. Do you ever call `testTripletArray = new ...` exception on the initialization? Please always do `testTripletArray.clear()` and then `testTripletArray.addall(theNewObjects)`.

Comment: I added `= new ArrayList` before adding the data from my word list. Also I have tried to clear the array list. When would I clear it? I currently, based on your advice added all of the edited elements to a holder triplet arraylist. After the for loop I cleared my testTripletArray and then added the values from the holder arraylist to my testTripleArray. However when I try to read the colour value they are all -1. Not sure why. I also notify the adapter after. ADDED your suggestion to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Your edit is not what i meant. I just wanted to know if you ever call `testTripletArray = new ...` somewhere else in your code we could'nt see. If yes then use my solution. Your edit does not work because if you really have the problem i described, you modify another object than in your adapter.

Comment: Removed the edit. This is my declaration: `private ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> testTripletArray = new ArrayList<>();` that is at global scope. My initilisation happens inside the function below with: `testTripletArray = wordAndDefinitionList.getDefinitionWordsTriplet();`. It's the only time I assign a value to it.

Comment: You could override `notifyDataSetChanged()` and call `super.notifyDataSetChanged()` and debug your items. Then you can check if there's the right color value. If not -> you're working with other objects.

Comment: You can try a workaround just to test (not the solution!): set in your adapter the field `private ArrayList<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> mInput = new ArrayList....` and add all items with `addAll()`. Then add a function in your adapter called `setItems(ArrayList<> newItems)` which clears the internal field and addAll new items. Call this function in `checkAnswerValues()` at the end. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Hi Beep. So I've taken a step back and I was a little confused by your second comment. Regardless I tried overriding the `notifyDataSetChanged` and it seemed all the colour indexes were still -1. That seems to me as if it wasn't using the correct list. I'll do more tests today and hopefully we can resolve it.

Comment: Even though your answer didn't completely help me it did help me explore the problem. I believe I wasn't calling `notifyDataSetChanged` after each iteration of the loop so I was losing the actual changing of the data. I also changed my Triplet to contain a String Enum that was based on "No Submission", "Match" and "No Match". With these values I set the background colour to change. Thanks for helping me beeb, have a nice day man! Please upvote if possible (would love to be able to comment on questions but under 50 rep)